# OAS3: Why is Accept header defined in Response?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen, oas

It says [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/) that one should not define the Accept header inside a OAS3 Yaml file as a parameter but in `responses.<code>.content.<media-type>`. Example:

```
paths:
  /employees:
    get:
      summary: Returns a list of employees.
      responses:
        '200':      # Response
          description: OK
          content:  # Response body
            application/json:  # Media type
              schema:          # Must-have
                type: object   # Data type
                properties: 
                  id:
                    type: integer
                  name:
                    type: string
                  fullTime: 
                    type: boolean
                example:       # Sample data
                    id: 1
                    name: Jessica Right
                    fullTime: true
```

This makes me wonder because if I create a client based on that OAS3 file using [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/releases) the string mentioned below "content:" (in my example `application/json`) gets used as is as Accept header when making the `/employees` call using that client. Thus the folling piece of code, which identifies the individual who is making use of my API ("userID"), would not have any effect:

```
DefaultApi api = new DefaultApi();
api.getApiClient().addDefaultHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.mycompany.userID.v1+json");
```

But as the owner of my API I don't want to provide a swagger file for each user.

Why does the Accept header in OAS3 get defined in the response section which in my opinion should only define the media type of the result?

Comment: OpenAPI does not support media types with dynamic parts. Is there a specific reason why you put the client ID in the `Accept` header instead of authenticating the client using standard authentication methods (API keys, OAuth, Bearer tokens, Basic auth, etc.)?

Comment: We had this idea to use the client in the Accept Header to be able to provide slightly different versions of our API for that very client. But you're right, we can identify the client using the Authorization header. Thanks for clearing things up!